# @model giving error in asp.net mvc 5 view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I am new to asp.net MVC, I have following controller,Model & view and I used database first approach with EF and using Storedprocedure to return results.

After creating EF6, I am able to see my model under edmx page ( Not under models)

I have attached sample code

controller

```
 public class TestController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Test/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            RBACv3Entities test = new RBACv3Entities();
            var result =  test.testing();

            return View(result.ToList());

        }
    }
```

Model

```
public partial class test
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
    <tr>
        <th style="background-color: Yellow;color: blue">Customer ID</th>
        <th style="background-color: Yellow;color: blue">Customer Name</th>
        <th style="background-color: Yellow;color: blue">City</th>
        <th style="background-color: Yellow;color: blue">Country</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.id</td>
            <td>@item.name</td>
            <td>NULL</td>
            <td>NULL</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

If I use @model in top of my page in Razor view, I am getting error and not allowing to use @model.test in top but I can access all results without using these at top. When should I use @model in top of Razor.

error

```
CS0119: 'Mypro.test' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context
```

View I used with @model

```
@model Mypro.test
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
    <tr>
        <th style="background-color: Yellow;color: blue">Customer ID</th>
        <th style="background-color: Yellow;color: blue">Customer Name</th>
        <th style="background-color: Yellow;color: blue">City</th>
        <th style="background-color: Yellow;color: blue">Country</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Mypro.test)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.name</td>

        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: would you mind posting the complete error and the `model` directive you are using at the top of your view?

Comment: CS0119: 'Mypro.test' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context

Answer (score 0):

I think your model should be  `@model IEnumerable<Mypro.test>`, since you want to iterate over it.

And then you'd have to correct your foreach loop:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.name</td>

    </tr>
}
```

To answer your question, when you should use  a model declaration with `@model`:
Your view will get compiled and if you omit the model declaration the compiler will just use `dynamic` as the type. This means it will not be able to check if the properties like `.Name`  actually exist during compilation. If it doesn't you'll get an error when trying to call that specific view.

Declaring a model helps you and the compiler to discover errors at compile time, by giving information about the structure of your model. You'll receive those nice squiggly red lines underneath your code, when the compiler is telling you, that you did something wrong.

Comment: Getting following error The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Mypro.testing_Result]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Mypro.test]'.

Comment: Change `IEnumerable<>` to `List<>`

Comment: Check the type of `result` by using `test.testing().ToList()` and `return View(result)`, both should be contain `IEnumerable<Mypro.test>`.